# Non-const reference to temporary works now?

Tags: c++, reference, move-semantics, rvalue, temporary-objects

With the introduction of move semantics, did the rule that you can only bind temporaries to const reference change? non-const seems to extend lifetime just as well.

```
 A getA() { return A();}  

 A & aref = getA(); //OK
 string & str = string("h") + string("i"); //OK again
```

This is with msvc, destructor for A does not get called before main exits.

Comment: What version of MSVC are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the rules are the same, you are not allowed to bind a rvalue to a non-const lvalue reference. MSVC is using a (dangerous) extension.

Comment: Can you explain the danger in being able to edit the return value from a non-const reference? Is it just the fact that people may try to return actual function scoped references to it, instead of aliasing to the temporary?

Comment: MSVC issues a warning indicating that it's a non-standard extension.